# Not able to open the Telerik report designer in VS 2022 and using .net 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

[Able to open the telerik report designer in the .net 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWbQU.png)

[but unable to open it in the .net core version 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU7w2.png)

I attempted to add the Telerik Report 2023 template to a .NET 6 project in Visual Studio 2022 but did not find the option to select the Telerik Report 2023 template specifically. While I do see the option for the Telerik Web Report Designer HTML5 page (R3 2023), I am encountering difficulty opening the TRDP file in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can open trdp, trdx and trbp files in the standalone or the web report designer (recommended). Visual studio designer opens type definitions (cs report files).

If you want to use VS designer, you can use the workaround described in this article and track the status of the feedback item:
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/how-to-use-vs-designer-in-dotnet-core
https://feedback.telerik.com/reporting/1383925-make-visual-studio-designer-work-with-net-core-a-k-a-sdk-style-projects

Resources:
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/overview
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/report-designer-tools/overview

Comment: How we can create a visual designer project in .net core 6. Can you please suggest me the steps?

we are getting this error: 
The reference telerik.reporting, version=17.2.23.1114,
culture= neutral,publictoken= could not be added to the project. this wizard will continue to run but the resulting project may not build properly

Comment: How to open Visual Studio Report Designer using .net core 6 in vs 2022